# Difficulties using DemonsRegistrationFilter in ITK

Tags: c++, itk

I'm trying to register two images using the ITK library and the DemonsRegistrationFilter. I have some problems setting up the two images that I want to register. When I compile, i get this error:

`ImageType` was not declared in this scope.

I first wanted to use the python wrapper but I didn't figure out how to do it so I have to code using c++ which I'm not really familiar. It is using template. If anybody can help or send me a simple working example, that would be great.

Regards,

Arnaud

Answer (score 1):

Since you are interested in Python bindings, you may be interested in the the 0.9 version of SimpleITK currently has added the Demons registration filters. You can [build it yourself](http://www.itk.org/Wiki/SimpleITK/GettingStarted#Build_It_Yourself) on the current git master or download a packaged [nightly version](http://www.itk.org/Wiki/SimpleITK/GettingStarted#Nightly_binaries) .

This will save you from some of these pesky C++ template issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have compiled correctly both ITK and your project with cmake?  Here is an example of registration http://www.itk.org/Wiki/ITK/Examples/Registration/LandmarkBasedTransformInitializer , but at this point what you should look first is the cmake file.
Or maybe you have defined Imagetype inside a function and you are using it in another function. It's not even a problem of templates, it's from c++ scoping.

Answer (score 0):

If you have built ITK correctly and have verified the build using Hello-World-ITK (see Section 2.2.1 of the itk software guide), then all you need to do is to define ImageType before you use it in your image-file-reader/demons-filter.

So you need a line like this at the beginning of your program

```
typedef itk::Image<unsigned char, 3> ImageType; //Pixel type and dimension of your image
```